# Make Tunderbird a bit more Apple-/Gmail-Like (Multi Line Mail List)

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

Is there any way to get Thunderbird to display the List of Messages like Gmail or Apple mail does? (First Line: Sender and Date/Time, Second Line: Subject)

Comment: This is not the right site for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=441414) that would require someone highly skilled to solve it, along with several month's worth of effort.